# Tablayout+viewpager in fragment, need to clear a edittext data in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have developed a project with `Tablayout` with 3 `viewpager` items, getting data in `edittext` from each `viewpager`, I need to clear all the data from `viewpager` and set all us empty, when button click event occurs which was set in last `viewpager` item.

This is parent `fragment`, `Homefragment`.class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    final ViewPager viewPager = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.viewpager2);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    next = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.nxt_btn);


    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
        }


    });

    return view;

}


private void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {
    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Customer_details(), "Customer Details");
    adapter.addFragment(new Order_details(), "Order Details");
    adapter.addFragment(new Payment_details(), "Payment Details");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}


    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View innerview = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            setupUI(innerview);
        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    //unbinder.unbind();
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    public void onButtonPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(null, MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                    && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                // handle back button
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                getActivity().finish();
                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

}

}
```

Customer.class

```
public class Customer_details extends Fragment {

public static int selectedid;
public static EditText cname, cnumber, cnumber2, caddress, cpincode, clandmark;
public static Spinner spinner, snum, snum1, sp1, sp2;
public static RadioGroup radioGroup;
public static RadioButton radioButton;
TextView ctype, name, contact1, contact2, dispatch, address, pincode, landmark, source;
private PayOrder_Interface pay;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cdetails, container, false);

    cname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.cname);
    cnumber = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.cnumber1);
    cnumber2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.cnumber2);
    caddress = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.caddress);
    cpincode = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.cpincode);
    clandmark = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.clandmark);

    String[] values = {"Select", "Retail", "Bulk"};
    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    final String[] value = {"Select", "+91", "+64", "+355", "+213", "+214", "+54", "+374", "+43", "+994", "+1", "+973", "+880", "+32", "+1-(441)", "+591", "+387", "+267", "+55", "359", "+673"};
    snum = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    String[] val = {"Select", "+91", "+64", "+355", "+213", "+214", "+54", "+374", "+43", "+994", "+1", "+973", "+880", "+32", "+1-(441)", "+591", "+387", "+267", "+55", "359", "+673"};
    snum1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner4);

    String[] v = {"Select", "Online", "Existing", "Sales Team", "Store", "Zomato"};
    sp1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_2);

    String[] b = {"Select", "GaarG Store 1", "PG Tech"};
    sp2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_bulk);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected

            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioButton1:
                    // switch to fragment 1
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton2:
                    // Fragment 2
                    break;
            }
            selectedid = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
           radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedid);
        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, val);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, value);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, v);
    ArrayAdapter<String> bulk = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, b);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    adapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    adap.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    bulk.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    snum1.setAdapter(a);
    snum.setAdapter(adapt);
    sp1.setAdapter(adap);
    sp2.setAdapter(bulk);
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

    // String txt=(String)spinner.getSelectedItem();

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            Object item = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);
          /*  if(item!=null){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),item.toString() + "Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
            //EventBus.getDefault().post(value);
            switch (parentView.getSelectedItemPosition()) {

                case (0): {
                    sp2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //Do Nothing
                }
                break;
                case (1): {
                    contact1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    contact2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dispatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pincode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    landmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    source.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cnumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cnumber2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    caddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cpincode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ctype.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    clandmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sp1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    snum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    snum1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sp2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    radioGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // radioButton_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //radioButton_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
                case (2): {
                    contact1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    contact2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dispatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    address.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pincode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    landmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    source.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cnumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cnumber2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    caddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cpincode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    clandmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ctype.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    snum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    snum1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    sp1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    sp2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    radioGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //  radioButton_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // radioButton_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    return view;
}
public String getEditetxtValue() {
    return cname.getText().toString();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                    && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                // handle back button
                Intent a = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
                getActivity().finish();
               return true;
            }
           return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Order.class

```
public class Order_details extends DialogFragment implements 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private static final String[] FLAVOURS = new String[]{"Venilla", "Stawberry", "Chocalate", "Mango", "Pineapple"};
public static EditText edittext, edmessage;
public static Spinner spinner, sp, select;
public static AutoCompleteTextView textView;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {

        edittext.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(year));
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.activity_odetails, container, false);
    edmessage = (EditText)  view.findViewById(R.id.ed_cake);
    String[] egg = {"Select", "Egg", "Eggless", "N/A"};
    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_e);

    String[] weight = {"Select", "0.5kg", "1kg", "1.5kg", "2kg", "2.5kg", "3kg", "6kg", "5kg", "4kg", "4.5kg", "3.5kg", "7kg", "8kg,", "7.5kg", "10kg"};
    sp = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_wt);

    String[] time = {"Select", "8Am- 9Am", "11.30pm-11.45pm", "9am-10am", "10am-11am", "11AM=12PM", "12PM-1PM", "1PM-2PM", "2PM-3PM", "3PM-4PM", "4PM-5PM", "5PM-6PM", "6PM-7PM", "7PM-8PM", "8PM-9PM"};
    select = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_t);

    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.au_flavour);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, egg);
    ArrayAdapter<String> p = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weight);
    ArrayAdapter<String> d = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, time);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    ArrayAdapter<String> au = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, FLAVOURS);
    p.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    d.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp.setAdapter(p);
    textView.setAdapter(au);
    select.setAdapter(d);

getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.
LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    return view;
}
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ed_date);
    edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDatePicker();
        }
    });
}
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                    Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
public void setupUI(View view) {
    if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View innerview = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            setupUI(innerview);
        }
    }
}
private void showDatePicker() {

    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    date.setArguments(args);

    date.setCallBack(ondate);
    date.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
}
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                    && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                getActivity().finish();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Payment.class

```
public class Payment_details extends Fragment {
public static TextView payment, advance, balance, discount, extra, extra_amount, delivery;
public static EditText e_amount, e_advance, e_balance, e_discount, e_extra, e_extra_amount, e_delivery_charges, e_remark;
public static Spinner spinner;
Context context;
Button addextra, reset, save;
private LinearLayout laytype, layamount, laybalance, laydiscount, layexamt, laydelivery, layextra;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_payment_details, container, false);

    e_amount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtAmount);
    e_advance = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtAdvance);
    e_balance = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtBalance);
    e_discount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.e_discount);
    e_extra = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.e_extra);
    e_remark = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.e_remarks);
    e_extra_amount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.eextra_amount);
    e_delivery_charges = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.e_delivery);
    addextra = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_extra);
    reset = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);
    save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save2);
    String[] ptype = {"Select", "Cash", "EDC", "Online", "NEFT", "Cheque", "Not Paid"};
    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_pt);

    laydiscount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    layextra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    layexamt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    laydelivery.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    if (Customer_details.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Bulk")) {
        payment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        advance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        balance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        e_advance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        e_balance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    textWatcher(e_advance);
    textWatcher(e_discount);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ptype);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

    addextra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int click = 0;

        //int i=0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //  int count =++_clicks;
            if (click == 0) {
                click = 1;

                laydiscount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layextra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layexamt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                laydelivery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
                click = 0;
                laydiscount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layextra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layexamt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                laydelivery.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }

    });


    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                clear();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            }           

private void textWatcher(final EditText edit) {
    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        int result,r=0;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            result = 0;
            //r=0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int e = parse(e_amount) - parse(e_advance);
            if (edit == e_discount && parse(e_discount) == 0) {
                result = e;
            }
            else{
                result = e - parse(e_discount);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            e_balance.setText(String.valueOf(result));

        }
    });

}

private int parse(EditText edt) {
    String s = edt.getText().toString();
    if (s.matches(""))s = "0";
    return Integer.parseInt(s);
}


public void clear() {

    Customer_details.spinner.setSelection(0);
    Log.v(Customer_details.cname.getText().toString(), "name");
    try {
        Customer_details.cname.setText("");
        Customer_details.snum.setSelection(0);
        Customer_details.cnumber.setText("");
        Customer_details.snum1.setSelection(0);
        Customer_details.sp2.setSelection(0);
        Customer_details.cnumber2.getText().clear();
        Customer_details.caddress.getText().clear();
        Customer_details.cpincode.getText().clear();
        Customer_details.clandmark.getText().clear();
        // Customer_details.radioButton.setChecked(false);
        Customer_details.sp1.setSelection(0);
        Customer_details.spinner.setSelection(0);
        Customer_details.cnumber.setText("");
        Order_details.spinner.setSelection(0);
        Order_details.textView.setText("");
        Order_details.sp.setSelection(0);
        Order_details.edmessage.setText("");
        Order_details.edittext.getText().clear();
        Order_details.select.setSelection(0);
        e_amount.setText("");
        spinner.setSelection(0);
        e_advance.setText("");
        e_balance.setText("");
        e_remark.setText("");
        e_discount.setText("");
        e_extra.setText("");
        e_extra_amount.setText("");
        e_delivery_charges.setText("");
        spinner.setSelection(0);
        e_amount.setText("");
        e_advance.setText("");
        e_balance.setText("");
        e_remark.setText("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("MYLOG", "Message was not handled " + e.getMessage());

    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cleared ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

I have tried to clear the items by this method,

1. `edittext.setText(" ");`
2. `edittext.getText().clear();`

Only Order and Payment class data alone get cleared Customer data couldn't cleared. How to fix my problem?

Comment: try to set this and try `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` inside `setUpViewPager()` method

Comment: Yeah!! Thanks @MohammedFarhan it's working bro Thanks a lot

Comment: @MohammedFarhan Again not clearing the editext in 2nd and 3rd tab viewpager, it only clearing first tab viewpager, sometimes its working and sometimes not clearing

Answer (score 1):

try to set this `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` inside `setUpViewPager()` method

**Upate**

By default `setOffscreenPageLimit()` will be set to 1, that means youll have 2 fragment pages active at once. Since you need to clear the texts from `EditText` of all the three fragment pages, then setting `setOffscreenPageLimit(3)` (because you are using 3 fragments) will have all 3 fragment page active and helpful in making necessary changes in all of them. For more information see the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

> void setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)
>   Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18272793)

Comment: @Jodocus - well, the answer seems to have been an comment at first. According to OP's comments, it was sufficient to solve the problem. So IMO this post does "provide an answer to the question", and what's more: it's a helpful answer.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Then it should be formulated as such. Right now, it is still a comment, even if it contains the essence of the answer. It should explain what it does and why it is necessary as well.